# How to creating a Soap server on https port other than port 80

Tags: php, linux, apache, soap

We are building, for the first time, a soap server for communicating with some of our vendors. For security purposes, we are looking at creating a soap web server that will listen on a port other than port 80 and use SSL. The server we are going to use is an new UBUNTU Linux server.

Can anyone provide some guidance or provide some documentation on best practices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The port/ssl options you'd be using would be specified in your [apache config](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html), rather than any business logic in PHP.

Setting up a SOAP service to listen on a particular actor URI is super easy: set up your wsdl to describe the functions which can be called; and then use the [SoapServer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapserver.soapserver.php) object to delegate all incoming requests to a secondary class to handle all the calls using either the `'classmap'` option in the constructor or the `setClass()` method of the SoapServer class; and define an `'actor'` in the `SoapServer` object constructor.

Comment: We decided to use the Apache Virtual host to enable the SSL port 443 but hide port 80 from being exposed.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to address that HTTPS is likely to use port 443 by default. So that would be one less problem.

Comment: "Like to *address*" - I see what you did there.

Comment: Well, I guess that about sums it up. Sometimes I ask the dumbest questions. Thanks for clarifying and being kind with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are many frameworks that make creating a soap server much easier. Take a look at thr [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/), and search for some [tutorials online](http://electrotek.wordpress.com/2008/04/19/soap-web-service-with-zend-framework/).